# Query high frequency firebase data at a lower frequency

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, esp8266

We're currently logging measurements to a Firebase database every 3 seconds.
But I want to graph the data over different periods, sometimes 5 mins, in which case 3 seconds resolution is ok( ~100 points). However if I want to see how it changes over 12hrs at the 3second resolution, I'll have 14,400 points. 
For the longer time periods, I want to drop the resolution to reduce the data points.

As we're using Firebase there's no backend to query the database and then filter the data, it's the UI that queries the DB so it has to be in the query.

- Is there any standard methodologies for handling this? (or common names for this that I can search on)
- Does anyone know a Firebase specific solution while querying
- Is it best to save whether this is 1min,5min,10min,1hr data when the data is first saved? (this is a less preferred solution as the data being set to firebase is from a small ESP8266 microcontroller without a huge amount of memory)

Many thanks in advance

Example data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with a variant on option three, pushing the data into 3 different locations depending on time interval, 3sec, 1min, 10min
[image]

This means I'm not sending up any extra information, just to a different location. 
When you do the queries, while limited to fixed intervals, I can just query those three locations